# Проблема с определением связей в БД. Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel

Задача стоит такая: Необходимо передать пользователю заранее подготовленный PDF-файл по нескольким выборкам. Он заходит на сайт, выбирает необходимые ему пункты. Необходимо сделать сие чудо в Laravel.

напр.:

1. Магистр — степень образования
2. Инженер — направление
3. Инженер производстенного цеха — выбранна профессия

и далее по выбранным пунктам ему отправляется PDF файл.
Конкретно таблица full_data хранит в себе именно эти варианты выборок и файл подходящий к ним.

Возможно, что центральная таблица должна быть другой, но на данный момент только такой вариант появился.

Вопрос у меня такой, какие связи использовать в Laravel?
[image: БД]

Answer (score 0):

```
name_of_profession->full_data и ко всем остальным - hasMany
category_of_personnes->full_data и ко всем остальным - hasMany
direction_of_education->full_data и ко всем остальным - hasMany
minimum_level_of_educations->full_data и ко всем остальным - hasMany
p_d_f_uploads->full_data и ко всем остальным - если 1 pdf к одной записи в full_data тогда hasOne, если нет то - hasMany
```